# Error when trying to view transaction details

Tags: transactions

Every time i try to click on any transaction history, it says, "Error. Transaction not available at this time."

Does anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Reason i'm asking is because i know copay is usually very quick with sending their bitcoin, however, the receiving end had yet to receive anything from copay.

Comment: And there is no way it got sent to the wrong address cause I scanned the QR code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: I believe this is a copay bug and should be asked here: https://github.com/bitpay/copay/issues